# What is the meaning of this type cast?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

SomeView.h

```
@interface SomeView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> 

- (void)setPage:(int)page;

@end
```

SomeViewController.h

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

SomeViewController.m

```
#import "SomeView.h"
#import "SomeViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [(SomeView *)self.view setPage:1];
}
```

What is the meaning of `(SomeView *)self.view`?

In the real code, it seems doing the magic of inheriting the functionalities from `SomeView` to `self.view` ...

*Reference:* The original [source code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Listings/Classes_ZoomingPDFViewerViewController_m.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your question doesn't apply out of the context of the **original** source.

Controller's view there is set explicitly by IB in the **storyboard**. That means that `self.view` is set to a custom `SomeView` class, but the compiler doesn't know that! That's why it is casted.

So it looks like a plain `UIView` to the compiler but in reality is a `SomeView` that needs access to its methods (so we tell the compiler 'don't worry this is a SomeView, go on and treat it like this'). I hope that this makes sense.

PS. You'll have to download the actual project to see what is really going on since the answer is to be found in the storyboard

Answer (score 1):

since `self.view` is a `UIView` you will need to cast it to your `SomeView`

So,

`SomeView *someView = self.view;` will give you a warning
So you cast it

```
SomeView *someView = (SomeView *)self.view;
```

Its not magic, its just casts the `UIView` to `SomeView`, `self.view` is defined as `UIView`
But its an instance of `SomeView` class, so inorder to use `SomeView` functions you will need to cast it

Comment: Why "`self.view` ... is an instance of `SomeView`"? `SomeViewController.m` only `import "SomeView.h"`, `self.view` is _only_ an instance of `UIView`.

Comment: Bcause Objective-C is dynamically typed, and despite it's declared as UIView, if you assign it to an allocated SomeView property, it will bye an instance of SomeView. This is how polymorphism works.

Comment: @H2CO3 do you mean `(SomeView *)` is equal to `[[SomeView alloc]init]`?

Comment: No it does not alloc a new one it just casts the slef.view since slef.view is really a someview

Comment: Why "self.view is really a SomeView"? self.view should be `UIView *` _only_.

Comment: @ohho See my answer. It explains why it's a `SomeView`

Comment: @ohho SomeView is a subclass of UIView, so SomeView is a UIView too :)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a typecasting from `self.view` to `SomeView` to access functionality of `SomeView`.

As your view controller already loads `SomeView`, but `self.view` will return an instance of `UIView`, that's why it is needed to typecast this to avoid warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
[(SomeView *)self.view setPage:1];
```

that means your self.view is type of SomeveView

```
SomeView *someVw = [[SomeView alloc]init];
self.view = someVw;
```